# How to assign a serial port to my bluetooth phone?

Tags: bluetooth, devices

I used `hcitool scan` to get the MAC address of my phone.

Then I used `sdbtool browse` to find the channel of the "Serial Port" service.

I put this information into `/etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf` and this is what the file looks like:

```
#
# RFCOMM configuration file.
#

rfcomm0 {
    # Automatically bind the device at startup
    bind yes;

    # Bluetooth address of the device
    device 00:00:00:00:00:00;

    # RFCOMM channel for the connection
    channel 00;

    # Description of the connection
    comment "...";
}
```

***Note:** The MAC address and channel are in there... I just don't want to print them here.*

I restarted the `bluetooth` service and went to `/dev` - but I couldn't see `rfcomm0` or anything close to it in there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that your phone doesn't have serial port support?  My old blackberry didn't.
I'd also advise you to try Blueman, which can scan and show the services available on your phone AND automatically bind it to network manager for tethering (although admittedly I think the latest bluez does that second part too now).

Comment: My phone definitely has serial port support - it works fine in BitPim on Windows.

Comment: ...and as mentioned above, I used `sdptool` to find available services. One of which was "serial port".